# Skip to a particular element of Queue(for the class Queue defined in System.Collections) in C#, without using foreach

Tags: c#, enumerator

I am using a queue to store members of a class i have defined.
After a specific fixed interval of time , i need to evaluate if there have been objects added to the queue and if they have been added, process them to get a required signal.

Now, i dont wish to use foreach loop, every time, since it would iterate through every member of the Queue.
i just want a way to skip to the element which had been last processed, so i can process fresh information.

The queue does get Dequeued , but only after it reaches a fixed, say 200 elements.
so the last 200 elements are retained

Whats a good way to do this without foreach/enumerator

I am using one thread for queuing/dequeuing and another for processing the information. After it gets to 200 elements it maintains that count in the queue.
I can use foreach, but i want to save myself some processing by skipping to the element which was previously processed directly

Comment: What does this have to do with locks/threads? Is this just another take on Producer/Consumer?

Comment: "The queue does get Dequeued , but only after it reaches a fixed 200 elements. I also want to retain few of the elements which have been processed." So the queue just stores items until it gets to 200 elements and then you clear (most of) it? It doesn't sound like normal behavior for a queue, which is usually used to control flow with a limited resource. You could just switch to a `List<Element>` and use indexing.

Comment: y dont you store processed elements index and use it later on?

Comment: @HackerMan The OP's problem is that you can't use indexing on a Queue.

Comment: y dont you use `List<>` instead?

Comment: I am using one thread for queuing/dequeuing and another for processing the information. After it gets to 200 elements it maintains that count in the queue.

Comment: It's a first in First out operation ,using a list would present different set of problems. I can use foreach, but i want to save myself some processing by skipping to the element which was previously processed directly

Comment: @novice You could use a `LinkedList<T>` and keep track of the previously processed node.

Comment: Right now i am storing the last processed node in an object, then comparing it with all elements in the queue, till last processed node has been found. would using a linkedlist<T>, be better?I think i may not be able to do what i had asked for , but anything that reduces processing would be good

Comment: @novice Yes, with a `LinkedList<T>` you can go directly to the node in question.

Comment: Ok i think i got it, linked list will be bulkier but no issues there. So i have to use linklist.Find(value), but that is O(n), did i really save any processing here?

Comment: @novice, you could maintain reference to last processed item in linkedlist and move forward(to [the next item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4t9w6be(v=vs.110).aspx) ) once it is needed. That would be O(1)

Comment: Yes, exactly what i have implemented aleksey, old question, i was trying to make it more lucid. Any way i can do it for a Queue though?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to uses queue as queue - dequeue and process. If you need to store "processed items" - just put them into another queue/list/whatever.

If you need proper multithreaded access (based on "locking" tag) - use [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).